# How do English speakers say one is in a spot where they can be easily hit?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Like one is on the line of sight or line of target but not about weapons.

This sentence:

Don't sit there, you're on the _______ .

Don't sit there, you're _______ .

Suppose a death ray of sunlight passes through a hole in the wall to where one is seated.

Comment: a sitting duck?

Comment: **sitting duck** implies a sentient enemy, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Any of these would work: you're a sitting duck,
you're in the danger zone,
you're at risk,
you're on the edge

Answer (score 1):

Other possibilities:

That's an **exposed position**. Don't sit there.

You're **vulnerable to** sunlight there. Move to another place.